# opengl matrix multiplication

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix

If I have a current matrix in OpenGL of C, and I apply the following code:

```
   glMultMatrixf(M);
   glMultMatrixf(M2);
```

What does the Current transformation matrix look like? In the red book it states that using glMultMatrix*(M) does this: CM. But also that doing the above makes this happen: M(M2v) where M2 gets applied before M. In this case M would be the left operand, but in the former M is the right operand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do;

```
glLoadIdentity();
glMultMatrixf(M1);
glMultMatrixf(M2);
glMultMatrixf(M3);
```

Then the resulting matrix is M = M1 * M2 * M3;

If you apply a vertex `v` to this, it is multiplied like so: `v' = M*v = M1*M2*M3*v`

I don't really understand your confusion though, what is the 'former case' you're referring to?

Comment: The OP posting the question sounds like he has some confusion between Mathematical convention and Computer Science matrix computation.

Comment: So I assume that M3*v happens before M2 gets multiplied. I don't understand why the red book states that MultMatrix*f(M) multiplies the current matrix C by M (CM) when in your explanation every time a matrix multiplication is applied, it is applied as the left operand, not the right, as in (CM)

Comment: @SamAdams: It *is* applied to the right. It's applied to the right of all *previous* matrices. The current matrix, as built up by all previous matrix commands is multiplied with the given matrix, and the given matrix is on the right.

Comment: so M1*M2 happens followed by the result of that * M3 ? I thought it went in reverse order, so that M2 * M3 happens before M1 * the result of M2*M3?

Comment: @SamAdams: Matrix multiplication is associative. So you can change the grouping of M1*M2*M3 all you want (just not the *order*). You can think of it as M1*(M2*M3), or (M1*M2)*M3. Either way results in the exact same matrix.